Класс Active первому результату запроса
Нужно первому элементу запроса добавлять класс Active в div . Перерыл весь Stackoverflow - ничего не подходит под мой случай.
<?php
                          $sql_item_for_shop = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM phones_item WHERE hide!='1' AND id!='$row[id]' AND main_page_show='1' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 8");
                          while ($row_item_for_shop = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_item_for_shop)) {
                              $options_sum = 0;
                              $sql_device_for_item = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT device_path FROM phones_device WHERE id='$row_item_for_shop[device]'");
                              $row_device_for_item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_device_for_item);
                          
                              
                          
                          
                              echo "
                              <div class='carousel-item' style='$row_item_for_shop[background_custom]'>
                                 <div class='container-fluid d-flex vh-100 align-items-center'>
                                     <div class='d-block w-100 text-light'>
                                     <div class='row'>
                                         <div class='col-12 col-lg-6'>
                                         <a href='/phones/$row_item_for_shop[alias]/' title='$row_item_for_shop[name]'>
                                           <img class='img-fluid d-block mx-auto' style='max-height:70%;' src='/uploads/images/collections/$row_device_for_item[device_path]/$row_item_for_shop[alias]/large-$row_item_for_shop[normal_image]' title='$row_item_for_shop[name] — $row_item_for_shop[short_description]' alt='$row_item_for_shop[name] — $row_item_for_shop[short_description]'>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class='col-12 col-lg-6'><p class='mt-4 mb-1 weight-700 text-uppercase'><a class='text-dark' href='/phones/$row_item_for_shop[alias]/' title='$row_item_for_shop[name]'>$row_item_for_shop[name]</a></p>
                                          <p class='weight-500 text-uppercase'>".$price_text."</p></div>
                                     </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              ";
                          }
                          ?>```


Добавьте счетчик в цикл и добавляйте класс, если это первая итерация.
